# undefined method `size' whit shoulda-matchers and Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

i try test a simples validation validate_presence_of using should-matchers and Rspec and FactoryGirls but when i run get this error:

```
undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

My test is:

```
context "when create new user" do
  let(:consumer) { create(:consumer) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

in my Consumer.rb i have:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :email, :cpf, :phone_number, :birthday, :message => :attrs_blank,:on => :create
```

and my FactoryGirls have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :consumer do
    association :vendor
    association :branch
    association :client
    name { Faker::Name.name }
..
```

i try use `subject { FactoryGirl.create(:consumer) }` in place of `let(:consumer) { create(:consumer) }` but get the same error, what is wrong ?

UPDATE:

complete error:

```
Consumer when create new user should require name to be set
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/models/consumer.rb:58:in `valid_phone?'
```

this validation is the problem:

```
validate :valid_phone?
```

apparently this is the problem, the `phone_number` is `nil`:

```
def valid_phone?
  @p = self.phone_number
  @bool = true
  if @p.size == 11 && @p[2] != "9"
    @bool = false
  elsif @p[0].eql?("0")
    @bool = false
  elsif @p.length > 11 || @p.length < 10
    @bool = false
  end
  errors.add(:phone_number,:error_phone) if @bool == false
end
```

I modified the test to:

```
let(:consumer) { create(:consumer,:phone_number => "5182969611") }
```

but the problem persists.

Comment: From where the `size` method is coming, I am not seeing it.

Comment: i update my question whit the answer

Comment: `@p` is `nil`.Do you have `phone_number`?

Comment: ```let``` is lazy evaluated, so your consumer actually is not created unless you explicitly call it. That might be a problem. Try to use ```subject { FactoryGirl.create(:consumer, :phone_number => "5182969611") }``` now with phone_number provided.

Comment: 1) you can use `let!`. 2) What `it` points to in your test ? 3) What about `before` ?

Comment: Please add `puts self.phone_number` to the `valid_phone?`, see if it really isn't `nil`